# How to correctly append numbers at the end of a string in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to rename a certain string when a new object is created to something like "Object Name - Copy (1)", then if it has already been copied (has "- Copy (num)" at the end), then just increment that number.

The thing I am doing right now is:

```
Object.Title = $"{object.Title} - Copy";
```

Which is very bad for user experience, because it won't tell the user which copy it is right from first sight and then as I am setting a title length limit, this implementation exceeds that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by object you mean an instance of a class, you can use a static variable that is shared by every instance, as a counter:

In the constructor use the current value of the counter to name the instance and then increment it.

Here is a demo:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class InstanceCounter
{
    static int _instanceCounter = 0;
    static string _title = "Object counter";

    private string _instanceTitle;

    public InstanceCounter()
    {
        _instanceTitle = _title+"copy (" + _instanceCounter + ")";
        _instanceCounter ++;
    }

    public string Title()
    {
        return _instanceTitle; 
    }
}


public class InstanceCounterClient : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        InstanceCounter ic0 = new();
        Debug.Log(ic0.Title());
        
        InstanceCounter ic1 = new();
        Debug.Log(ic1.Title());
        
        //...
    }
}
```

Save this code in a script named **InstanceCounterClient**, attach it to a game object and press play Then look at the messages at the Console:

[image]

If the class you need to count the copies is derived from a **MonoBehaviour**, new instances cannot be created with new().
MonoBehaviours must be attached to game objects to be instantiated.

With a MonoBehaviour, we can increment the static variable in the **Awake()** event function, which is called by the Unity engine when a game object is instantiated in a Scene.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class InstanceCounterMB : MonoBehaviour
{
    static int _instanceCounter = 0;
    static string _title = "Object title";

    private string _instanceTitle;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _instanceTitle = _title+" copy (" + _instanceCounter + ")";
        _instanceCounter ++;
        
        //Just to check the instance name
        Debug.Log(_instanceTitle);
    }

}
```

If we attach this last script to 2 game objects in a Scene, we will see the same 2 messages in the console again, after pressing play.

Note that if a Scene is reloaded, **Awake()** functions will be called again for every object in the Scene, because the game objects will be instantiated again:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html